# How to derive the count of highest recursion level a recursive function will support?

Tags: java, recursion, callstack

How to derive the count of recursion level a recursive function will support without actually executing the function with different complex inputs. For e.g. when I execute below code it displays a level of recursion when the function throws stack overflow error. When I execute the program it displays "Recursion Terminated at 8373".

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        RecursiveExperimenter experimenter = new RecursiveExperimenter();
        experimenter.experiment();
    }
}

class RecursiveExperimenter {

    public void experiment() {
        try {
            A();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println("Recursion Terminated at " + counter);
        }

    }

    private void A() {
        counter++;
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
        A();
    }

    private int counter = 0;
}
```

How could I have derived that number without actually executing the function but by applying some mathematics? For this questions assume the stack size of the thread to be 1 MB. I am not clear about the overhead of the stack frame itself.

Thanks.

Comment: It's JVM implementation dependent. Also, how do you know your thread's stack size is 1MB?

Comment: It also depends on the method being recursed, since local variables are usually allocated on the stack too.

Comment: 65536/8373 ~= 125bytes/frame assuming identical stack frames for each call. Also, do not forget that main() has a stack frame of indeterminate size as well. Just out of curiosity, does the number repeat consistently between different runs?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: No, output is not consistent. It is in the range 8365 - 8380. This is new to me. What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you hard-coding the amount of memory available somewhere? It looks like your stack size is not "assume 1MB" consistently. I think the answer to your question is no, you can not arrive at this number "mathematically".

Comment: No there is no hard coding anywhere. I am using eclipse (Kepler) with all default settings. I assumed java thread stack size to be 1 MB. I might be wrong. I should verify it.

Comment: Things like this will be affected by JIT, too.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that this question has no specific answer.

There is no such thing as *"the count of recursion level a recursive function will support"*.  Nothing inherent in the concept of recursion imposes any limit on the level of recursion "supported".

In practice, the level of recursion you can achieve depends on the total stack memory available and how much memory each invocation takes up.  This will in turn depend on the physical memory limits of the machine, the amount allocated to the JVM, the implementation of the JVM, whether or not the code has been optimized, and probably several other factors. It's even possible for heap memory to be the limiting factor if each invocation allocates large objects on the heap.

In other words, the achievable recursion level for a specific program is 100% dependent on the environment in which the code is run.